# How do I return column names in my query results?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using this query:

```
Select *
From table1
Join table2 on
     table2.column1
     + table2.column2
     + table2.column3
     + table2.column4
LIKE '%'
     + table1.column1
     + '%'
ORDER BY table1.column1
```

How do I also return the column name where the result was found. For example, if the word "bob" in table1.column1 is found in table2.column3 (call this column "comments"), then the query result should have "bob", followed by "comments" (t2.c3), followed by all other columns (t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t2.c4).

Comment: yes. I used it yesterday quite successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select x.bob, y.column1, y.column2, y.column3, y.column4
From table1 x
Join table2 y on
     table2.column1
     + table2.column2
     + table2.column3
     + table2.column4
LIKE '%'
     + table1.column1
     + '%'
ORDER BY table1.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do, but you can get 'columns' where data is found by this simple trick. Modify as necessary.

Instead of doing `select *`, list out all your result columns. Then for each result column add another column wrapped in isNull() to indicate what column it came from.

```
Select 

table2.comments,
isNull(table2.comments, null, 'comments') col1,

table2.column2,
isNull(table2.column2, null, 'column2') col1

From table1 
Join table 2 on 
     table2.column1 
     + table2.column2 
     + table2.column3 
     + table2.column4 
LIKE '%' 
     + table1.column1 
     + '%' 
ORDER BY table1.column1
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is not only get the query to return all the rows in table 2 that contain the word "bob" but also to tell me which column it found the word "bob" in. Ideally this would be done by returning the column name.

Comment: The best way would be to get the query results, and then "parse" the results using a programming language, like PHP or Java, to determine which of the columns had "bob" in it.  You could easily do this using arrays, as long as you know that table structure for the table you are querying.